# MySQL Query w/ 2 tables to get the desired results

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pull in the related postings based on the posting category. So where all category ids match the category id field.

**Additional clarification:**

I've been experimenting all morning and still no luck, and this is where I am at now. Note the $CatID in the ON clause is from a previous query above this one and the value is correct.

```
$sql = "
(SELECT 
    a.id,
    a.Price,
    a.City,
    a.Country,
    a.Title,
    a.Description,
    a.Category, // contains the corresponding ads_cate.id. 
    a.recdate,
    c.cateName,
    'item' AS type FROM ads_list AS a 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ads_cate AS c 
            ON $CatID=a.Category 
            WHERE to_days(now())<=(to_days(recdate)+14) 
            ORDER BY RAND())
";
```

**And as tested:**

```
echo $CatID . $row['Category']; // Outputs 3 3 which is correct.  Category is 3 ads_cate id is also 3 for this record.
```

My results is pulling in duplicates and ALL ads regardless of Category.

Comment: do you have a query that does not work?  do you have php that does not work?

Comment: Can you describe a bit more clearly the output data you would like to see?

Comment: I added my latest code and data above. I seem to be on the right track, but I cannot get this processing as I want.

Comment: I don't even see how the code you've posted would run at all. Try posting your table schema's and your desired output and it'll be easier on all of us.

Comment: This is my worst post ever hands down. I added my table schemas here: http://pastebin.com/xxwgWUv5

Answer (score 1):

If **every** ad has a category, and assuming your `ads_cate` table has an `id` field:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
        a.id,
        a.Price,
        a.City,
        a.Country,
        a.Title,
        a.Description,
        a.Category, // contains the corresponding ads_cate.id. 
        a.recdate,
        c.cateName,
        'item' AS type 
    FROM ads_list AS a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ads_cate AS c 
    ON c.id=a.Category 
    WHERE to_days(now())<=(to_days(recdate)+14) 
    AND a.Category = $CatID
    ORDER BY RAND()
";
```

Comment: Both of your assumptions are correct. Now no results are showing. I should mention I am using: MySQL 4.1.14. I should also clarify there are in fact ads_list items that meet the query requirements.

Comment: Based on your direction I finally got this damn thing working! Thanks much for your tip.

Comment: Now I noticed that I just used the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` I pasted from tour original code. My intention was to suggest an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't understand your question, when using join, you can use `SELECT DISTINCT` to stop the duplicates.  Beyond that, I don't understand the question.

Comment: I am having a heck of a time explaining this. Let me try again. I am basically trying to only pull in ads_post records where the Category (relational id field of ads_post) is equal to $CateID which is the id field of the ads_cate table. I could not use id (created a separate query for this) because it conflicted with the id of the ads_list. Does this help?

Comment: Part of my problem is I named my table wrong in my previous comment. The tables under discussion are: ads_cate and ads_list just to eliminate that confusion I created.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code. Had to modify some based on bfavaretto's suggestion, but it's working as expected now:

```
$sql = "
(SELECT
a.id,
a.Price,
a.City,
a.Country,
a.Title,
a.Description,
a.Category,
a.images,
a.recdate,
a.images,
a.image2,
a.image3,
a.image4,
a.imgWidth,
a.imgHeight,
a.ftype,
c.id,
c.cateName,
a.email,
'item' AS type FROM ads_list
AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN ads_cate
AS c ON c.id=a.Category WHERE to_days(now())<=(to_days(recdate)+14) AND a.Category =     $CatID ORDER BY RAND())";
```